Get the 3D centroid of a GeoDataFrame
I have a 3D GeoDataFrame (GeoPandas 1.0.1) that I'd like to extract the 3D centroid from.
Currently, this is not working because it drops the 3rd dimension:
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd

d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(1, 2, 3), Point(7, 8, 9)]}

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:3857")

gdf.dissolve().centroid[0].coords[:]
# [(4.0, 5.0)]
# expected: [(4.0, 5.0, 6.0)]

How would you proceed to be as efficient as can be (large dataframe of linestrings at hand)?

As a workaround, one can first use the get_coordinates() method specifying include_z=True, then computing the mean and exporting to a list, packed in a tuple(), packed in a list again:
[tuple(gdf.get_coordinates(include_z=True).mean().to_list())]
# [(4.0, 5.0, 6.0)]

One can also directly export to a numpy array:
gdf.get_coordinates(include_z=True).mean().to_numpy()
# array([4., 5., 6.])


There's a bunch of different definitions of "centroid", and most of them don't involve an arithmetic mean of the X and Y. So, while this gives an answer, it's pretty much the wrong answer for multipoint, linestrings, and concave polygons, multi-part polygons, or polygons with interior parts. A better answer would use the "inside" centroid, then intersect that with the TIN facets of the 2.5D geometry to find a true point on the surface.
